# Generate signature for a policy using hmac sha1 in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Generated a policy , signature using hmac sha1 to upload AWS image 
But Issue : Signature mismatches
Below is the code:

```
$policy=  '{ "expiration": "2017-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",       
              "conditions": [
                {"acl": "public-read" },
                {"bucket": "imgupload" },
                ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
                ["starts-with", "$Filename",""],
                ["starts-with", "$foldername", ""],
                ["starts-with", "$fileext", ""],
                ["content-length-range", 0,5242880]
        ]}';


 $base64_policy  = base64_encode($policy); 

 $secret_key     ="cffystdhasssssdas"; 

 $signature      = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',$base64_policy,$key,true));
```

Comment: This code couldn't possibly create a signature mismatch. Because it computes a signature, but the signature is never used.

Comment: Please show everything you're doing.  Also, what are the nonstandard values `$Filename`, `$foldername`, and `$fileext` supposed to do?  What does the corresponding form look like, and what is the error?

Comment: Using this policy and signature to upload using postman by hitting AWS url,  passing below values in request body :    {"key":"2059","acl":"public-read","success_action_status":"200","Content-type":"image/png","AWSAccesskeyId":"ASBJSFBJDJ","Policy":$base64_policy , "Signature":  $signature}